# No @EnableOAuth2Resource in Spring Cloud Security 1.1, invalid access token after upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

As the title, there is no @EnableOAuth2Resource in version 1.1.
How can I achieve the same thing in 1.1?

From what I read in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security, There is no @EnableOAuth2Resource annotation in Spring Cloud 1.1. You just use the regular @EnableResourecServer from Spring OAuth.

Before I update to 1.1, I can use @EnableOAuth2Resource to check token from another Auth Server by providing userInfoUri in properties file. It works fine until I update the version.

```
  spring:
    oauth2:
      resource:
        userInfoUri: http://auth:9003/api/me
        preferTokenInfo: false
```

After I update to 1.1, I just change the @EnableOAuth2Resource to @EnableResourceServer. However, it shows invalid access token when I call an protected api.